# Caching Tweets using PHP

Tags: php, caching, twitter

I am developing an website TwittyBlog.com and what I am trying to do is to cache tweets for couple of hours and check new tweets after that time to improve the response time (otherwise it checks tweets of that particular user everytime he or others visit)

What do you recommend me? What is the best practices to cache the tweets? I am not quite at PHP as I am in .NET environment since I decided using PHP for my personal projects (I've been using it for 4 months not so often)

The main idea of the TwittyBlog is to create a blog website for a user out of his/her tweets.

Thanks.

Comment: Convert the tweets into an RSS feed, use a RSS library that comes with caching and done.

Comment: @hakre: Sounds really nice... +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [JG Cache](http://www.jongales.com/blog/2009/02/18/simple-file-based-php-cache-class/) it's a PHP library that helps you cache pretty much anything using Memcache.